# Automate HAPI FHIR partition creation

Tags: hapi, hapi-fhir

I have a requirement to automate the partition creation (http://example.com/DEFAULT/$partition-management-create-partition) endpoint either via fhirClientProvider or other api that would allow to programmatically create partition. Is there a way to automate that or a sample code that I can follow?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the use case? you POST to that endpoint to create a partition. Which part do you need to automate?